# use Ubuntu 11.04 on my computer to actually control my Ubuntu 11.04 on a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, thin-client

Is it possible to have Ubuntu 11.04 server x64 on my remote server and also have Ubuntu 11.04 server x64 installed on my computer.

Well duh, ya thats possible. But what Im getting at is that my remote server has immense resources.

so I wanted to to somehow be able to control my server thru a GUI, and I do not want to install vnc on the server. So whatever I do on my computer, im actually triggering and doing it on my server.

My remote server has Ubuntu-desktop installed right now.

Comment: A server doesn't have a GUI. And if it has it shouldn't have one.

Comment: true, but sometimes its easier to do things

Comment: You should be administering Windows then - the usability policy at most of the Microsoft's product groups would match your expectations far better than the Linux "everything should be doable from the command line within a maximum of 20 keystrokes" philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can use to achieve it:

[X11 Forwarding using SSH](http://www.linux-tip.net/cms/content/view/302/26/)
[X11 Forwarding Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html)

Your server has a next-to-100% chances of having an SSH service configured and running on it, and if it does have ubuntu desktop installed on it like you say, you will be able to "tunnel" x11 apps through ssh with those tutorials.

Your request is somewhat unusual, and chances are that you will find there is a good reason why most servers are not managed that way.

I have no idea what kind of GUI application you might use to efficiently administer an Ubuntu server, but if you find one you will be able to run it through ssh with this technique.

Comment: As a side note: you do not have to have an X server actually **running** on the server machine (this would also increase the attack surface and thus impose a security risk). Just the libraries which the X-based software is linked against need to be present on the disk (in the right locations).

Comment: Indeed. But something tells me security is not at the top of the list in this matter!

Comment: You should sez your avatar to Dilbert's pic with an attitude like this ;-)